# CloudKit, join or efficient way to add an item to list

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm using CloudKit to manage a list of messages (record type Message with a field title and body). All messages are public and I want to maintain which Message the user has read using the mobile app.

The app can have thousands of users and messages. And I use swift3.

I've think of different way to do it but they seems quite poor in term of performance:

- add a field 'readers' to Message which is a list of string corresponding of user Id. The problem is that if I want to add a new user ID I must load all the list. This is problematic for a mobile app in case of a lot of users have read the message. Can I lazy fetch a list field and add a value to it without downloading all the list (like in classic Orm)?
- add another record type 'Reader' which has two fields: a user ID and a message ID. I can't find a way to join Message and Reader in a predicate to download only Message that the user hasn't read. Is that possible?
- [As suggested by Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39780343/231456): add a record type ReadArticle in the private database that stores only a CKReference to a message. The problem is that we need to download all message ID before sending them in a NOT predicate.

I don't know how to solve this problem with a database like CloudKit.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

## Readers field

This approach is not ideal for the exact reasons you pointed out, and it additionally is unsafe as a `String` could theoretically contain anything.

## Reader object

Even if there was a way to get this to work you'd be storing user ids in the public database. That's probably not a privacy-conscious thing to do.

## ReadMessage Record in Private Database

Suppose you had a Record Type called `ReadArticle`. This object would contain exactly one field, a `CKReference` to a `Message` record.

Then, when someone reads a `Message`, you take the `recordId` of that `Message`, create a `CKReference` from it, and place that reference in the "message" field of a new `CKRecord` object of type `ReadMessage`. Then, you save it to the user's private database. Because it's a `CKReference`, it won't actually take up hardly any space in iCloud because it's just a pointer, and because you'd use the user's private database there's no need to explicitly identify the user.

Then when you want all unread messages, fetch the `ReadMessage` record, and create a NOT predicate to receive all `Message` records where the record id is not any of the read ones. CloudKit definitely supports NOT predicates, but if it happens to not support NOT predicates specifying record ids, than you could use some other unique field on message instead.

Comment: But if I understand, the mobile app need to download the full unread message stuff before doing the predicate and resend all this data in the predicate? This is problematic for a big amount of unread message, isn't it? Or you have a way to join private and public database in predicate (can't find it)?

Comment: That's true. There may be a much better way, that's just what I thought of initially. I don't believe you can combine the databases in the predicate.

Comment: I add this solution to my post, but the problem of performance is still the same ;)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hopefully someone will find a solution .